# List data by combining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables (up_1, up_2, up_3). All of them have same db structure (id, value, date, time). I need to list them by certain date.

For example if I choose 17 November 2015, it will list all data on 17 November 2015.

Here's the example of data set

ucp_1

```
----------------------------
id, value, date, time
----------------------------
1, 2, 17/11/2015, 09:00
2, 2, 17/11/2015, 10:00
```

ucp_2

```
----------------------------
id, value, date, time
----------------------------
1, 2, 17/11/2015, 11:00
2, 2, 17/11/2015, 12:00
```

ucp_3

```
----------------------------
id, value, date, time
----------------------------
1, 2, 17/11/2015, 13:00
2, 2, 17/11/2015, 14:00
```

The result that I want to be displayed

result

```
-------------------------------------------------
value_ucp1, value_ucp2, value_ucp3, date, time
-------------------------------------------------
2, NULL, NULL, 17/11/2015, 09:00
2, NULL, NULL, 17/11/2015, 10:00
NULL, 2, NULL, 17/11/2015, 11:00
NULL, 2, NULL, 17/11/2015, 12:00
NULL, NULL, 2, 17/11/2015, 13:00
NULL, NULL, 2, 17/11/2015, 14:00
```

Is it possible to achieve these kind of result by SQL Query?

Comment: Why do you have three tables in the first place, if all of them have the same structure?

Comment: There several fields that different on each table and I don't put it here. I just simplified the table structure here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` all to combine different tables.

```
   SELECT value AS ucp_1_Value,
           NULL AS ucp_2_Value,
           NULL AS ucp_3_Value,
           `date`,
            `time`
    FROM ucp_1 
    WHERE `date` = '17-11-2015'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS ucp_1_Value,
          value AS ucp_2_Value,
          NULL AS ucp_3_Value,
         `date`,
          `time`
    FROM ucp_2 
    WHERE `date` = '17-11-2015'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS ucp_1_Value ,
           NULL AS ucp_2_Value,
           value AS ucp_3_Value,
           `date`,
           `time` 
    FROM ucp_3 WHERE `date` = '17-11-2015'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to merge your result with UNION ALL as subquery like this

```
SELECT
    merged.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        value AS value_ucp_1,
        NULL AS value_ucp_2,
        NULL AS value_ucp_3,
        date,
        time
    FROM up_1
    UNION ALL SELECT
        NULL,
        value,
        NULL,
        date,
        time
    FROM up_2
    UNION ALL SELECT
        NULL,
        NULL,
        value,
        date,
        time
    FROM up_3) AS merged
WHERE merged.date = '17-11-2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an other perspective.

**Query**

```
select  case when t.ucp_id = 'ucp_1' then  t.value_ucp end as value_ucp1,
        case when t.ucp_id = 'ucp_2' then  t.value_ucp end as value_ucp2,
        case when t.ucp_id = 'ucp_3' then  t.value_ucp end as value_ucp3,
        t.`date`,t.`time`
from
(
    select 'ucp_1' as ucp_id,value as value_ucp,`date`,`time` from ucp_1 
    union all 
    select 'ucp_2' as ucp_id,value as value_ucp,`date`,`time` from ucp_2 
    union all 
    select 'ucp_3' as ucp_id,value as value_ucp,`date`,`time` from ucp_3
)t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33c09e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize you DB structure. Create one table with the structure you are mentioned:

```
Table VDT
id_VDT, value, date, time
```

And tree tables with other fields that are linked to the first one:

```
Table_A
id_VDT, {first table fields}

Table_B
id_VDT, {second table fields}

Table_C
id_VDT, {third table fields}
```

Then run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM VDT, Table_A A, Table_B B, Table_C C
WHERE VDT.Date = {your date} AND 
      VDT.id_VDT=A.id_VDT AND VDT.id_VDT=B.id_VDT AND VDT.id_VDT=C.id_VDT
ORDER BY {your need}
```